# How to make emitted particles disappear when they hit a surface?

Tags: particles

I'm wondering, how to make emitted particles disappear when they hit a surface? Is it even possible? The *Boolean* modifier (*Difference* mode) doesn't seem to work...

My question came after watching a (nice) [Dereck Elliott tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M6ROAZnyMqo). He creates the boat splashes with particles, you can't see the particles going through the boat because the boat is closed, but if it was open, how to fix this?

Using the *Lifetime* can only work if the 2 surfaces are parallel.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/28739/how-can-i-make-particles-remain-stationary-on-a-surface/29029      https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/87691/particles-collide-with-first-object-then-die-on-second-collision  https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/72609/how-to-create-convincing-rain-with-a-particle-system

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the object that should make particles disappear when they come into contact with it, set the 'Kill Particles' option after enabling 'Collision' on the *Physics* tab of the *Properties* editor:

[image]

Comment: oh ok thanks a lot  ;)